# How do I stack, add, duplicate on MySQL with the same item id with maximum quantity?

Tags: php, html, mysql, numbers

Let's say my name was John. John has 2000 Marbles.

Except, you may only have 100 Marbles on one slot. He has 20 Slots of 100 Marbles each

If I were to create a table saying he has 2000 Marbles how would I do that?
Instead, it shows this:

```
John - 100
John - 100
John - 100
Becky - 65
Squid - 40
```

I would like it to say this:

```
John - 300
Becky - 65
Squid - 40
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT characters.name, inventoryitems.quantity 
FROM characters, inventoryitems, accounts 
WHERE characters.accountid=accounts.id and characters.id=inventoryitems.characterid and inventoryitems.itemid = 4001190 and accounts.banned = 0 
ORDER BY inventoryitems.quantity
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Feels very much like homework with little effort put into it before asking here.  Have a look at SQL aggregation functions like SUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with an `INNER JOIN` query and use [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function and [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html) clauses

```
SELECT a.name, SUM(b.quantity) as total
FROM characters a 
INNER JOIN accounts c
ON a.accountid=c.id
INNER JOIN inventoryitems b 
ON c.id=b.characterid 
WHERE b.itemid = 4001190
AND c.banned = 0 
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY total
```

Comment: Thank so you much, it worked!
I wish I could vote up for you but I can't :( I'm new here